# How can I make a disjunction of element selectors with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I need is something like this:

```
$('element1 or element2').mouseover(function()
{
   $('element3').show(effects,blah);
});
```

I hope I just overlooked this possibility in the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a comma to separate the selectors:

```
$('element1, element2').mouseover(function()
{
   $('element3').show(effects,blah);
});
```

The comma is the CSS syntax for [selector grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping).

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, you can just do `document.querySelectorAll('tag1, tag2');`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [a comma in the selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), or you can use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

```
$('element1, element2').mouseover(...);
$('element1').add('element2').mouseover(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just as you can specify it in CSS, just use a comma-separated list:

```
$('.element1, .element2').mouseover(function() { 
    $('element3').show(effects,blah); 
});
```